# QTreeWidget - disable dropping on top level

Tags: c++, qt

I have a [QTreeWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html) and I enabled the drag and drop. Despite I would like the users to be able to drag and drop items inside the tree I don't want them to drop any dragged item on the top level. How can I do that ?

Let's say that I have predefined categories which are the top level items and I don't want to extend that list. But in the lower levels the user can create any number of items and also she/he can move those items around.

Comment: Without checking I'd guess you need at least to inherit from QTreeView. I've never tried it. Try filtering selectedIndexes() and react to the normal drag events (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-draganddrop.html)

Comment: Try to use `QTreeWidget::invisibleRootItem` to get root item and disable `Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled` flag for it. If this doesn't work, reimplement tree widget's `dropMimeData` and block dropping if parent is null or invisible root item.

Comment: It will be much easier to use `QStandardItemModel` + `QTreeView` for such requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the help. It worked.

```
MyTreeWidget::MyTreeWidget( QWidget* aParent /*= nullptr*/ )
: QTreeWidget( aParent )
{
// ...
    auto rooItem = invisibleRootItem();
    rooItem->setFlags( rooItem->flags() ^ Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled );
}
```